# How can I get with a single python function the number of columns at each row of a 2D list with different number of columns on the rows

Tags: python, list

I create dynamically a 2D list with vectors (lists) of different sizes.
Is there any python function for getting the size of the lists on their rows? Looping I know how to do it.

Comment: the question is too vague, can you provide concrete examples of input/output?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was clear what I need. https://stackoverflow.com/users/10415286/jacob-warren already help me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple helper function using list comprehension.

```
def get_row_sizes(l):
    return [len(row) for row in l]
```